# While uploading data from csv to dynamodb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

> An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the
>   BatchWriteItem operation: The provided key element does not match the
>   schema: ClientError Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 24, in lambda_handler
>   'name':row.split(',')[1] File "/var/runtime/boto3/dynamodb/table.py",
>   line 156, in **exit** self._flush() File "/var/runtime/boto3/dynamodb/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please post your code, the data you're trying to insert in Dynamo and your table settings (primary key and sort key)